# How can i add static block in magento on category page?

Tags: magento-1.9, cms, static-block

I want to add a static block on my website Category page. This is the link of that page.

> https://flowerportal.in/online-flower-delivery/all-cities/bangalore

I have just created some banners for Bangalore product page but I don't know how to add a static block here. If you guys can help me regarding this then I will be really happy.

Comment: This is more of a programming question than a sysadmin question. Ideally, it'll be moved to a place where it's more likely to get good answers. You could expedite that process by clicking the "flag" option on the post and asking for a migration to Stack Overflow.

Comment: or to [magento.se], if such questions are on topic there. In the current state it would be off topic on SO as well.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the below code to your `catalog/product/view.phtml` according to your requirement and change the **block_identifier** with your identifier which includes the banners:

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('block_identifier')->toHtml(); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the product page is built with the help of PHTML and XML files, you can call a static block from the layout XML file or directly from the phtml file.

Since you want to call the static block for the particular condition, I would recommend calling the block from the phtml file.

To do so, open the phtml file and call

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('block_identifier')->toHtml(); ?>
```